# Securing ClientID and TenantID within a static web app - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-static-web-app, azure-app-registration

I have an react-application i am creating in a static web app - all this works fine but I want to remove the hard-coded values of the app registration. so I have it like this at the moment.

[image]

Obviously this is not good enough - so i created a key vault to store this info in.

[image]

So somehow i need to reference this clientid via the application settings and then grab the vital info out of the reference into my key vault and into my application.

How can i do this ? All i hear is that i can only do this for API's which doesnt seem good to me.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Sorry, I’m confused, can you access the values from the application settings in a static web app or not?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings

Answer (score 0):

Client ID is not sensitive. Also, you can enable managed identity on your Static Web App and use the identity to access Key Vault, where you store your configuration.

Comment: i have created an a managed identity. the ClientID is just a demo but deffo do not want the tenantID when i get to that part. any help in getting the info from the application settings into the code ?

Comment: It doesn't support as of now.

Comment: anyone got a clue on how we can do this or at least make it secure ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this as @indp said this is not possible at the moment with the key vault. So the best way of doing this is this way : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/static-web-app-image-analysis?tabs=bash%2Cvscode

Hope this helps people.